# How to check if variable is of list type? of dictionary type?

Tags: vimscript

In a plugin, I'm using `json_decode()` to obtain information from somewhere.

I've no control over the json structure, but expect a list of numbers under a key `foo`:

```json
{
  "foo": [10, 20, 30]
}
```

How to properly guard my operations with `get(l:json_object, 'foo')` so that they fail predictably when value received under `foo` isn't list? E.g. `{"foo": null}`, `{"foo": {"bar": "kaboom"}}`:

```
    let l:foo_list = get(l:json_object, 'foo')

    if __IS_LIST__(l:foo_list)    " <-- FIXME

        let l:hundreds = map(l:foo_list, "10 * v:val")

        echo join(l:hundreds, " -- ")

        " Expected output:
        " 100 -- 200 -- 300
    endif
```

What this fictional `__IS_LIST__` check actually looks like in Vimscript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
if type(l:foo_list) == v:t_list
```

Or in older versions of Vim:

```
if type(l:foo_list) == type([])
```

See [`:help type()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#type%28%29) for more details.

Comment: I still use `type([])`  for portability reasons.

Comment: Nice, thanks. I'd expected it was something trivial — but neither `:help List` nor [vim cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/vimscript) revealed the `type` function to me; and the question was somehow fruitless on web search. Hopefully, it won't be now.